# Search By Name in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ms-access-2007

I have the Follwing Code. To search by StdName but when i run this code it shows empty cells in datagrid view. Help me to correct this.

```
 private void btnSBN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String query = "Select * from Student where StdName like '*@Name*'";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 20);
        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = txtName.Text;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds,"SBN");
            dgStudent.DataSource = ds;
            dgStudent.DataMember = "SBN";
            dgStudent.Refresh();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Compiler shows no syntax error and no exceptions. but show empty cells in datagrid view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'*@Name*'
```

is your problem.

If you're looking for an exact match, don't have the '*'s.

If you're looking for an instance where the @Name is found somewhere in the StdName, use:

```
'%' + @Name + '%'.
```

You also shouldn't have @Name inside the quotes.  If it's an exact match:

```
StdName = @Name
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I want to ask that when i enter this query in MS ACCESS 2007 . by using % operator it shows no result in the query. but if i change it to * it shows the instance where @Name is found. Why these two operators are not working same in both c# and MS ACCESS 2007?

Comment: @MuzamilAbbas That's just the way it works. We have to use `*` in queries that are run from within the Access application itself, and `%` in queries that are executed from another application. (In most cases, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

When working with parameter queries remember that you should never have delimiters in the CommandText. If delimiters are required in the background the OleDbCommand object will take care of them for you.

```csharp
String query = "Select * from Student where StdName like @Name";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 20);
cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = "%" + txtName.Text + "%";
```